# Fridge Water Line Leaking

Tags: water, refrigerator, ice-maker

My fridge water line is leaking, not the line running from the wall to the fridge, but the line that is inside the fridge.  The issue is the connection where the inside line meets the outside line.  This is an image of where the issue is, the white tubing where it connects to the green is not connected very well anymore and water just sprays everywhere when the water goes through the line.

What piece(s) are needed to repair this?

**EDIT**
No fridge guru's around here that can assist in the name of this part?  Or what else can I provide so that we can track down exactly what this is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got down there and did some further digging and research.  Come to find out it was the plastic tubing that provides water internally to my fridge that was leaking where it connects to the piece in the image in my OP.

Fortunately, the plastic water line was only attached by a tension ring (apply some pressure and pull the line out) and I removed the water line, provided a new clean cut, and reattached and everything is fine and dandy again.